# php mail onclick on link execute mysql command

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, email, passwords

I'm trying to do a password reset using mail, so what will happen is the user will enter his email on the forgot password and on button click it will be sent to the email that is on the database. Now what i will do is give the user a new random password and to do this the user should click on the link on the email to verify that he really wants to change the password, will that be possible? Here is my code

```
    if (isset($_POST['mytxtmail']))
    {
        $newid = ($_POST['mytxtmail']);

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT EMAIL FROM members WHERE EMAIL='$newid'");
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'Mail  Successfully Sent to '.$newid;
    return false;   
    }
    else
    $to      = $newid;
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'Please Click here to Verify the Change of Password';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo 'Mail  Successfully Sent to '.$newid;

    }
```

Comment: if don't find the user, you echo "mail successfully sent.." ..

Comment: $newid is the users email, i did not use a username

Comment: If you find NO USER you say "mail sent" followed by return false; inthat case no mail will be sent... you are also missing the opening bracket of the else statement

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a long procedure to write the full code here.

One way you can do is, make a new column in your users table, let's say `pass_request_hash` , now whenever the user clicks on forgot password option and enters his e-mail ID and submits, an update query runs to dump a random value into `pass_request_hash`  for that user and at the same time a mail is sent with that same hash value and also his e-mail ID as `GET` parameters.

Now when the user has clicked on the link sent to him by e-mail, the link points to a PHP script which checks with the database if the hash and e-mail received from the `GET` parameter matches with those in the database, if yes then you can have another script getting executed to send a new password to that e-mail ID.

You can also set a timeout for that hash.

There are other ways to do it too, check out some of these tutorials:

- [One](http://www.newthinktank.com/2010/04/how-to-code-php-login-and-forgotten-password-scripts/)
- [Two](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1299)
- [Three](http://codetorq.blogspot.ae/2013/05/php-forgot-password-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should include the link in the email which would take the user to the password verification script (it could be the same you are using here, only add needed functionality).

Comment: What i want is when the user clicks on the link a mysql update commad will happen

Comment: Then you should add this functionality to your script or make another one. 

`if (isset($_GET['verify'])) { update mysql }`

Comment: cant understand, can you do it on the answer